# How to convert shapefile to fusion table?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-fusion-tables, shapefile, google-geocoding-api

I have some shape files (.shp) and am wondering how I can convert them so that they can be used by Google Fusion Tables.

I know that Josh Livni's fantastic website (http://www.shpescape.com) is the perfect answer to my question. However, at the time of posting this question, this website is not working (it's down).

I did some research, but everyone suggests shpescape.com. I'm wondering if there is an alternative solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](http://www.shpescape.com/) in your post doesn't work, but [this one](http://shpescape.com/): http://shpescape.com/ is working for me (no `www.` subdomain).

The source is open source and is located at: https://code.google.com/archive/p/shpescape/

(although google code has been archived)